# Getting Asian character set in output for python anaconda interpreter RRuntime errors

Tags: python, r, ipython, anaconda, rpy2

I just switched from Homebrew python to Anaconda python for various reasons and also upgraded my version of R.

One thing I have not been able to figure out is why it is printing out errors in what appears to be Korean or Thai script:

```
/Users/gms/anaconda/envs/evaluate_it/lib/python2.7/site-  packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.pyc in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    104         for k, v in kwargs.items():
    105             new_kwargs[k] = conversion.py2ri(v)
--> 106         res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
    107         res = conversion.ri2ro(res)
    108         return res

RRuntimeError:  eval(expr, envir, enclos) でエラー: 
    関数 "wald.test" を見つけることができませんでした
```

Not sure if this is specific to the particular library `rpy2` or Anaconda, or just R, since it is an R runtime error. Googling this did NOT help.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help at all, but that looks like Japanese. Where did you get the libraries from?

Comment: `conda install rpy2` ... I've used this library before and it never printed out Kanji characters. I could try uninstalling and doing a `pip install` of the same library to see if that makes a difference,

Comment: Can't use that version, due to various reasons. I'm stuck with Kanji, I guess! I am going to ask the maintainer of the library why this all of the sudden started happening.

Comment: Yep, it's only happening for the `rpy2` library. It's also happening for warnings. Kind of hard to debug when one does not know how to read Japanese.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ends up that I needed to set the locale for my Anaconda environment (specifically, for R) in my `.bash_profile` using the command `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. Still not sure why it was defaulting to Japanese.